# Inner join with 3 tables-

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, subquery

I have 3 tables to fetch data from,

```
mstr_store(new_site, Site_name...)
Sale_fy1819(New_site, MC_Code, Net_Sale_Units, dt...)
Sale_fy1920(New_site, MC_Code, Net_Sale_Units, dt...)
```

i am expecting below result,

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Store | MC_Code | Net_sale_units (fy1819) | Net_sale_units (fy1920)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have written below code, but shows error 1066, please help me to understand right way to code these type of queries.

```
SELECT 
    mstr_store.NEW_SITE,
    sale_fy1819.MC_Code,
    sale_fy1819.Net_Sales_Units,
    sls_fy1920.Net_Sales_Units
FROM
    mstr_store,
    sale_fy1819,
    sls_fy1920
        INNER JOIN
    sale_fy1819 ON mstr_store.NEW_SITE = sale_fy1819
        INNER JOIN
    sls_fy1920 ON sale_fy1819.Store_Code = sls_fy1920.Store_Code
WHERE
    sale_fy1819.DT >= '2018-09-01'
        AND sale_fy1819.dt <= '2018-09-30'
        AND sls_fy1920.dt >= '2019-09-01'
        AND sls_fy1920 <= '2019-09-30';
```

Comment: Remove these 2 lines `sale_fy1819,
    sls_fy1920` from the FROM clause. They are duplicating what is being done in the JOIN's

Comment: Without an explanation of what you want to do, sample data and desired results, any response is just guessing.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, will try.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that you want an aggregation query:

```
SELECT s.NEW_SITE, fy1819.MC_Code, fy1819.Net_Sales_Units,
       fy1920.Net_Sales_Units
FROM mstr_store s JOIN
     (SELECT new_site, MC_Code, SUM(Net_Sales_Units) as net_sales_units
      FROM sale_fy1819
      WHERE sale_fy1819.DT >= '2018-09-01' AND sale_fy1819.dt <= '2018-09-30'
      GROUP BY new_site, MC_Code
     ) fy1819
     ON s.NEW_SITE = fy1819.new_site JOIN
     (SELECT new_site, MC_Code, SUM(Net_Sales_Units) as net_sales_units
      FROM sale_fy1920
      WHERE sale_fy1920.DT >= '2019-09-01' AND sale_fy1920.dt <= '2019-09-30'
      GROUP BY new_site, MC_Code
     ) fy1920
     ON s.NEW_SITE = fy1920.new_site AND fy1920.mc_code = fy1819.mc_code;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, thanks for your inputs, Tried with this but there's one error says ( "Select" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : '(', with ).... Pls help...

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM
    mstr_store,
    sale_fy1819,
    sls_fy1920
        INNER JOIN
    sale_fy1819 ON mstr_store.NEW_SITE = sale_fy1819
        INNER JOIN
    sls_fy1920 ON sale_fy1819.Store_Code = sls_fy1920.Store_Code
```

you have written sls_fy1920 and sale_fy1819 twice. You should remove them.

```
FROM
    mstr_store
        INNER JOIN
    sale_fy1819 ON mstr_store.NEW_SITE = sale_fy1819
        INNER JOIN
    sls_fy1920 ON sale_fy1819.Store_Code = sls_fy1920.Store_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your code and that is what giving you problem. I have added comments (#) on the two lines with problems. You also included the tables you join and that would give you problems.
I also moved the date match from the were into the join in order to speed it up and make the code cleaner.

```
SELECT 
   mstr_store.NEW_SITE,
   sale_fy1819.MC_Code,
   sale_fy1819.Net_Sales_Units,
   sls_fy1920.Net_Sales_Units
FROM
   mstr_store
      INNER JOIN
         # You have to define what column in sale_fy1819, my guess is that it is called site but correct it!!
         sale_fy1819 ON mstr_store.NEW_SITE = sale_fy1819.site 
         AND sale_fy1819.dt between '2018-09-01' and '2018-09-30'
      INNER JOIN
         sls_fy1920 ON sale_fy1819.Store_Code = sls_fy1920.Store_Code
         AND sls_fy1920.dt between '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-30'
```